# Using Jupyter with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using the Ubuntu bash terminal on Windows 10 ([installation instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)), I installed Anaconda and have been using Jupyter notebooks without a problem. Unfortunately, Jupyter is unable to locate a runnable browser from within the subsystem, so I have to copy and paste the link it outputs in the terminal - but that is workable. The main issue comes when I try to open multiple notebooks. Normally, Jupyter would detect that a port (`8888` by default) is already being used and make a new one, but it seems to fail to detect this so that when I use the link it generates, I end up looking at the first notebook I opened instead of the new one.

Any idea what the issue might be? And, if not, how I can manually get around this?

Comment: Have you trying installing firefox or other browser to your subsystem and then try to run the browser with your choice of xwindows clients?

Comment: @scrappedcola No, I have not yet set up an X server to work with WSL. Do you know if there is a substantial performance disadvantage to do so?

Comment: I haven't noticed, but it probably depends heavily on the type of computations you are doing.

Comment: I used solutions from both answers `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 9888`. Works for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assign different port number manually when you start the notebook. For example:

`jupyter notebook --port=8889`

Comment: Ah thanks! This fixes the problem. Any idea why Jupyter might fail to detect the port already in use?

Answer (score 23):

try:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

Answer (score 14):

**Update:**
For some, the original answer below should still work.
For others, who get an additional error related to a `tcgetpgrp failed: Not a tty` message, there is no real fix at the moment. ([See this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10413))
Therefore, you need to use `jupyter notebook --no-browser` or set `c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False` in the config file `$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

**Original answer:**
I had the problem that Jupyter didn't find a file (complete error message in German):

```
Start : Dieser Befehl kann aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht ausgeführt werden: Das System kann die angegebene
Datei nicht finden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Start "file:///home/nico/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-1164-o ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Jupyter did work, but it didn't open my browser, when I typed `jupyter notebook`.

I found a very simple solution to this:

1. Create the Jupyter Config file:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

or

```
touch $HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

2. Now add the following line to the config file (by using `nano` or any other text editor):

```
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

Now, my WSL uses the `wslview` command to open the default browser in Windows. (I think)

If `wslview .` does nothing, you might need to manually install [wslu](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu).

**Side note:**
This solution also works for `jupyter lab`, but you have to use
`c.LabApp.use_redirect_file = False` in `$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py`.
Or even better `c.ServerApp.use_redirect_file = False` in `$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.py`.

Comment: I had a working setup that started throwing this error message all of a sudden. Turns out all I had to do was restart wsl as shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744219/jupyter-lab-networkerror-running-on-wsl2

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue with browser, I got

```
No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

I installed WSLU https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu.
Then I got

```
Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start --h
+ ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

`jupyter-notebook` does not supply url as a parameter to `wlsview`. It passes a path with file to browser. eg

```
file:///home/myhome/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-5058-open.html
```

with actual url

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=19b5f1fefb13f5fc315b05991175d1f8cb5ada9baaca6804" />
    <title>Opening Jupyter Notebook</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    This page should redirect you to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't,
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/tree?token=19b5f1fefb13f5fc315b05991175d1f8cb5ada9baaca6804">click here to go to Jupyter</a>.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Create a file `jupyter-notebook-browser` with a content to extract actual url

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/file:\/\///')
url=$(grep -oP 'href="\K([^"]*localhost[^"]+)' "$file")
wslview "$url"
```

then run  `jupyter-notebook --browser=jupyter-notebook-browser`

or define `BROWSER` variable and run

```
export BROWSER="jupyter-notebook-browser"
jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: The second option does not work for me. The jupyter notebook runs in WSL and I get two paths, one file:// and other localhost and file option automatically opens in the browser. However, it just shows a blank page and does not redirect to the notebook. If I open the localhost path, then it shows the notebook. Is it possible that jupyter-notebook opens the localhost path directly?

Comment: This works for me; i find the error message quite cryptic and it is only your answer that explains that it has something to do with (in)ability to locate a browser. Thank you.

Comment: There is no need to install wslu. Replace the last script line `wslview "$url"` with `cmd.exe /C start "$url"`.