# Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: jupyter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed wsl(Windows Subsystem for Linux) with ubuntu and jupyter notebook on it. When I run my jupyternote book, I get this error message. Could you give me some advice? Many thanks in advance!

---

Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1

- Start "file:///home/purit/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-26-op ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
  ```

Comment: Start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start "file:///home/purit/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-26-op ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: When using `start`, you can't use the `file:///` protocol. You need the actual path to the file only. `file:///` is only for use in a web browser's address bar. `start` is also a Windows command.

Comment: Thanks so much. Then, could you kindly tell me how I should fix it?

Comment: Also, if you move your comment into the answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: I followed this tutorial when I install "jupyter notebook." on Ubuntu. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: This also occurs with `jupyter lab` and the answer from @Maiteya Verma (specifying --no-browser) also works for this.

Answer (score 53):

This one worked for me.

```
jupyter notebook --port=8889 --no-browser
```

You can also checkout [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882266/using-jupyter-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux) if any other solutions work out for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Yea this seems to be the trick: jupyter notebook --no-browser or jupyter lab --no-browser. (I guess that a browser cannot be opened in WSL which is throwing this error)

Answer (score 39):

Here's a nice walkthrough that explains how to set up jupyter notebook to run with WSL and launch your browser in Windows without this error:

https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-on-wsl-while-using-firefox-on-windows-5a47ebfae4c1?gi=fc70b24c75bf

There are two important steps:

1. Run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` to generate the file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` then change the following line:

`c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`

2. Add your browser to `~/.bashrc` E.g.

`export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'`

Don't forget to source bashrc:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

That should fix the error without having to run `jupyter notebook --no-browser`.

Comment: I did that and the error went away. But when it opens the browser I get: Your file couldn’t be accessedIt may have been moved, edited or deleted. ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Found my mistake. The line should stay as `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`. So I only had to uncomment it, not change it.

Comment: In my case i didn't add browser settings to bashrc

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the problem occurs because the Jupyter notebook tries to open the browser after it is started. To disable this, follow these steps:

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
$ cd /home/YourUser/.jupyter/
$ nano jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Now you need scroll down and find "NotebookApp.open_browserBool", remove the # and set it to **False**. Save your config file and start jupyter notebook again.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting. I actually get the same error. I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 but never had a problem with an older version. My question is, does the jupyter notebook you're setting up still work?
Because for me, the links it gives actually do still work and I can run everything perfectly. So it might be worth it to just try the links.

Comment: Yep. the links works fine like you said. Thanks so much. Still, I want to know why we got the error message, though. :)

Comment: Also, I want to know how I can get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

I have done following steps,

1. Run `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
2. Run  `sudo nano /home/{username}/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`
3. Removed `#` from => `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = True (I changed True to False)`
4. And also i added windows path as default notebook_dir `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/mnt/d/Jupyter/'`