# GreatExpectations' data_docs (tutorial) fail to work correctly on WSL2

Tags: jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, great-expectations

I'm testing out `Great Expectations` by following [this tutorial](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/tutorials/getting_started/tutorial_overview):

Unfortunately my jupyter notebooks could not open the browser direclty at first, but I was able to fix that behavior by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814002/start-this-command-cannot-be-run-due-to-the-error-the-system-cannot-find-the/63638811#63638811), which has to do with **Jupyter notebook configuration**. Unfortunately some other problems persist which require assistance.

1. When I create an expectation, the `data_docs` opens on an URL like :

   ```
   file:///home/user/workspaces/gx_tutorials/great_expectations/uncommitted/data_docs/local_site/validations/getting_started_expectation_suite_taxi/demo/__none__/20230122T183749.724235Z/3aa0a5a68a2bbe5abd3b08ea9739616c.html
   ```

   But this doesn't open since my `/home` folder isn't on windows, where the browser is installed. **So I have to work around it manually everytime** by replacing `file:///` with `file://///wsl.localhost/Ubuntu-20.04/` like this

   ```
   file://///wsl.localhost/Ubuntu-20.04/home/user/workspaces/gx_tutorials/great_expectations/uncommitted/data_docs/local_site/validations/getting_started_expectation_suite_taxi/demo/**none**/20230122T181115.325050Z/3aa0a5a68a2bbe5abd3b08ea9739616c.html
   ```
2. When I am able to open the validation results via the relevant jupyter notebook as described in the [tutorial page: how to run validation and inspect your validation results](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/tutorials/getting_started/tutorial_validate_data#how-to-run-validation-and-inspect-your-validation-results), I click on the link to the invalid result and I get a `404`, the file does not exist in this directory:

   ```
   file://///wsl.localhost/Ubuntu-20.04/home/user/workspaces/gx_tutorials/great_expectations/uncommitted/data_docs/local_site/validations/getting_started_expectation_suite_taxi/demo/20230122-213919-my-run-name-template/20230122T213919.318761Z/444fa93fe34e9e162c5f910bca5b5916.html
   ```

   But when I check my directory, this file is there, and I have to rename the `444fa93fe34e9e162c5f910bca5b5916.html` to `sample.html` manually, and open it via **Windows' explorer**, which is **a work around** I would like to avoid, and have a permanent solution instead.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using WSL2, I think the better answer is to install a browser (Chrome or Firefox) there. Good instructions here:

https://www.freshtechtips.com/2022/12/install-firefox-google-chrome-in-wsl.html

There are other tutorials out there that show how to launch your Windows browser, but they're never going to help with the fact that GX wants to use the Linux /tmp directory.